# Generic Version of Linq Sort by value type contained in Foo

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have the following Method

```
public static List<T> MergeAndSort<T>(List<List<T>> listOfLists) where T : Foo
    {
        List<T> list = listOfLists.SelectMany(bunch => bunch).ToList();

        list.OrderBy(x => x.FooLongMember);

        return list;
    }
```

I look for a solution that provides a completely generic version. Currently I need to specify what T is as well as specify the specific member name within Foo in order to order by such member. The member currently is of type long. Can I rewrite the function to at least not have to specify that I pass in a List of Lists of type Foo? I target C#, .Net4.0. Thanks

Comment: `list.OrderBy(x => x.FooLongMember)` is not going to work like that!

Comment: @Freddy it cant work because `OrderBy` does not sort the list but rather returns an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Sorry my wrong, indeed this is not working as indicated. What would I need to change to have the List sorted by FooLongMember contained in T?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> MergeSortWrapper<T,TKey>(
      IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> listOfLists,
      Func<T,TKey> keySelector) 
{
    return listOfLists.SelectMany(bunch => bunch)
                      .OrderBy(keySelector);
}
```

-

```
var result = MergeSortWrapper(listOfListOfFoos, x => x.FooLongMember).ToList();
```

Comment: The question is why would anybody want a function for wrapping such a simple linq statement? Also the naming of the function might mistakenly make you think its performing a [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Comment: Maybe because the function is run in multiple tasks? Agree the wording is misleading, will change it.

Comment: @L.B, thanks it solves my question, just wondering, do you think there is a more optimal solution, optimal in terms of faster. Just passing in a List of List of type long and merging and then sorting the resulting list is about 8 times faster. Obviously there is overhead involved with a wrapping object but I am surprised its that much slower.

Comment: Marked your suggestion as the answer I was looking for, thanks for your help. I am pretty new to Linq as is probably obvious. Would really appreciate if you had a better idea how to merge the objects ordered by the object containing member.